# How To Bind Data From Database to DataGrid In Wpf?

Tags: wpf

how to Bind data to DATA GRID In WPF ,I get Following Error "Set connectionId threw an exception". On DataGrid
I have Following Code.

```
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RollNo" Width="50" Binding="{Binding RollNo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Width="100" Binding="{Binding City}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PinCode" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Pincode}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>


                </GroupBox>
```

Comment: You should post some relevant code.

Comment: @Rudy my code for result is Session("strResult") = "<center>"
        Session("strResult") += "<h3>Quiz Result</h3>"
        Session("strResult") += "<p>Points: " & intScore.ToString() & " of " & intTotalQuestion.ToString()
        Session("strResult") += "<p>Your Competency: " & Int(intScore / intTotalQuestion * 100).ToString() & "%"
        Session("strResult") += "<p>Time Spent: " & tsTimeSpent.Minutes.ToString() & ":" & tsTimeSpent.Seconds.ToString()
        Session("strResult") += "</center>"

Comment: Please click "edit" on your question and add there the code, well formatted, so anybody can read it easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store your data in `Session`. You can use a plain `string` variable for this. 
Anyway, if you want to send HTML email you should mark it: `message.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Comment: sir i want result should travel on three page after that i want to email it

Comment: @NitinTurankar - Now you see how important is asking well! Nobody is a medium around here.